# PowerShell escape underscore in Where clause

Tags: powershell

I am looking to filter out results that end in underscore[some numeric value] e.g. Thing_20201116

```
 | Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "_*"}
```

Powershell v5.1

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help kind people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*_*` - that will be anything with _ in it.

To be more specific you'll need `-notmatch` which takes a regular expression (see ref for [where-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) and [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions).)

Example:

```
ls | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "_\d+$"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -notmatch with a regex: `|Where-Object {$_.name -notmatch "_\d"}`